# Celery: using Redis as a result_backend and RabbitMQ as a message broker

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am a novice to Celery, Redis, and RabbitMQ.

Currently, I'm using RabbitMQ as a message broker, and nothings are set in configuration. (with Django, MySQL)

I am wondering if it's possible to use Redis as a result store in backend, at the same time, RabbitMQ as a message broker.

The thing I know is only adding some settings, `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just set:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<db_number>"
```

replacing `<password>`, `<hostname>`, `<port>` and `<db_number>`.

Comment: Thank you, matagus. Really?? My question is about whether it's possible to set `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://~"` and `BROKER_URL = "amqp://~"` simultaneously. I'm sorry for re-questioning. I just want to confirm that again.